# Pushing django-app to heroku

Tags: django, git, deployment, heroku, procfile

I have a some Django project and want deploy on Heroku.
I am trying to push my app to heroku and I get the following message:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 22, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 5.04 KiB, done.
Total 22 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:fierce-tor-2115.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:fierce-tor-2115.git'
```

Files list:

```
$ git ls-files
.gitignore
Procfile
project/__init__.py
project/apps/main/__init__.py
project/apps/main/admin.py
project/apps/main/forms.py
project/apps/main/models.py
project/apps/main/tests.py
project/apps/main/views.py
project/environ.py
project/manage.py
project/project/__init__.py
project/project/settings.py
project/project/urls.py
project/project/wsgi.py
requerements.txt
```

git config

```
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:fierce-tor-2115.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

My Procfile:

```
$ cat Procfile 
web: python project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
$ cat requerements.txt 
Django==1.5c1
psycopg2==2.4.6
```

Heroku App I created with next command:

```
heroku create -s cedar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your filelist appears `requerements.txt` and should be `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i would recommend you to check this guide
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django
 and try to push test empty project created following steps in guide.

If it pushes successfully try to find differences ( as i know heroku is case sensitive for example ).

Comment: My project was created in this guide. Project name `fierce-tor-2115`. Directory with git repo `testproject`.